# Using WiredFunction with parameter to display results in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have below component. I am trying to use wired function to get the data and show it using  `<template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">`. Referring the documentation with slight tweaks - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="ApexWireMethodToProperty" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={contacts.data}>
                <template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">
                    <p key={contact.Id}>{contact.Name}</p>
                </template>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/ContactService.getContactList';

export default class WireFunction extends LightningElement {
    contacts;
    contId = '';

    @wire(getContactList, { contId: '$contId' })
    wiredContacts({ error, result }) {
        console.log('Inside wireFunction =====> ' + this.contId); // is blank
        console.log('result =====> ' + result); // is undefined
        if (result) {
            this.contacts = result;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.contacts = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
// ContactService.cls
public with sharing class ContactService {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContactList(String contId) {
        String query = 'SELECT '
                     + 'Id, Name, Title, Phone, Email '
                     + 'FROM Contact';
        if (String.isNotBlank(contId)) {
            query += ' WHERE Id = :contId';
        }
        query += ' WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED ';
        system.debug(Database.query(query)); // I can see the result in debug logs
        return Database.query(query);
    }
}
```

When load the page I see this statement twice in console logs. **Trying to understand why there is two calls in this case?**

[image]

And I also get this Error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the wired function to:

```
@wire(getContactList, { contId: '$contId' })
wiredContacts({ error, data }) {
```

The property names must always be error and data (if you don't spread the properties into parameters you can call the single parameter whatever you like). Make other changes in the body of that function as needed.

You then need to change the rendering to use:

```
        <template if:true={contacts}>
            <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
```

since you already grabbed the "data" from the response and stored that in this.contacts.

As to the double calls to the wire function, this is normal. You get an initial call with an empty value (error and data undefined) during component initialization, then the real call once the wire's reactive parameters have values (here error or data will be defined).

Comment: It worked that way. Thanks for clarifying about the double call